Java program will not work while trying to run lingua
I am trying to write a Java program that can run this code from this library https://github.com/pemistahl/lingua
The code is successfully built in Gradle using the ./gradlew build command. I'm able to run it in standalone mode using ./gradlew runLinguaOnConsole --console=plain but when I am trying to run my Java file this is what is says:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
        LanguageDetector cannot be resolved to a type
        LanguageDetectorBuilder cannot be resolved
        Language cannot be resolved to a variable
        Language cannot be resolved to a variable
        Language cannot be resolved to a variable
        Language cannot be resolved to a variable
        Language cannot be resolved to a type
        
        at RunLingua.main(RunLingua.java:8)

This is the code for RunLingua.java :
import com.github.pemistahl.lingua.api.Language;
import com.github.pemistahl.lingua.api.LanguageDetector;
import com.github.pemistahl.lingua.api.LanguageDetectorBuilder;

public class RunLingua {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Build the language detector
        final LanguageDetector detector = LanguageDetectorBuilder
            .fromLanguages(Language.ENGLISH, Language.FRENCH, 
            Language.GERMAN, Language.SPANISH)
            .build();

        // Detect the language of the input text
        final Language detectedLanguage = 
            detector.detectLanguageOf("languages are awesome");

        // Print the detected language
        System.out.println("Detected language: " + 
            detectedLanguage);
    }
}

Note: The Java file is outside of the library folder
I have no clue what the issue is because I am new to Java and to incorporating Kotlin libraries. I'm not sure if it is because of the Java file itself or its location within my project stack. My current file organization is ParentFolder > linguaLibraryFolder, RunLingua.java where the ParentFolder holds both the library folder and java file.

Please don't post images of code, errors, logs, or other text; see [ask]. Instead include a [mcve] so that others can reproduce the issue. How do you manage dependencies? Include your gradle or maven build script.

"The code is successfully built in Gradle" Obviously not. "so the environment is all good" Definitely not.

The class RunLingua should be in a file named RunLingua.java, not runLingua.java.
